# Opscenter Agent 4.1.2: Remote Monitoring

Tags: agent, datastax, opscenter

The usual method for installing the opscenter agent whether via the opscenter server or manually is to install it on the cassandra node server.

Is the agent configuration flexible enough that it can run anywhere and monitor cassandra remotely? Are there complexities that may not be readily apparent?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr - No

While there are several config options that would let the agent monitor certain JMX metrics remotely, you would lose critical metrics and functionality such as disk and CPU metrics, and the ability to stop/start/configure the Cassandra process.  These all require the agent to be running locally.

Comment: Ok. A variation then. What about having the agent listen on a management interface while cassadra is active on another?

Comment: You can configure what interfaces the agent binds to in address.yaml:  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.1/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html